# Combine DataFrame Rows to eliminate NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, nan

I have a DataFrame created from a data logger, where each point of data has it's own timestamp that looks like this:

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val1": [ 1, np.nan, np.nan, 11, np.nan, np.nan, 21, np.nan, np.nan, ],
        "val2": [ np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 12, np.nan, np.nan, 22, np.nan, ],
        "val3": [ np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 13, np.nan, np.nan, 23, ],
    },
    index=pd.to_datetime( [
        "2021-01-01 00:00", "2021-01-01 00:00:01", "2021-01-01 00:00:02",
        "2021-01-01 00:01", "2021-01-01 00:01:01", "2021-01-01 00:01:02",
        "2021-01-01 00:02", "2021-01-01 00:02:01", "2021-01-01 00:02:02",
    ] )
)
```

```
                     val1  val2  val3
2021-01-01 00:00:00   1.0   NaN   NaN
2021-01-01 00:00:01   NaN   2.0   NaN
2021-01-01 00:00:02   NaN   NaN   3.0
2021-01-01 00:01:00  11.0   NaN   NaN
2021-01-01 00:01:01   NaN  12.0   NaN
2021-01-01 00:01:02   NaN   NaN  13.0
2021-01-01 00:02:00  21.0   NaN   NaN
2021-01-01 00:02:01   NaN  22.0   NaN
2021-01-01 00:02:02   NaN   NaN  23.0
```

I don't actually need the precision of when each single data point was logged. I would like to condense the DataFrame by eliminating the `NaN`s and merging the lines that are very close together. the result should look like this:

```
                     val1  val2  val3
2021-01-01 00:00:00     1     2     3
2021-01-01 00:01:00    11    12    13
2021-01-01 00:02:00    21    22    23
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible simplify solution for resample per minutes with `max` or `min` or `first` use:

```
df = df_orig.resample('Min').max()
print (df)
                     val1  val2  val3
2021-01-01 00:00:00   1.0   2.0   3.0
2021-01-01 00:01:00  11.0  12.0  13.0
2021-01-01 00:02:00  21.0  22.0  23.0
```

Comment: Thanks. My real dataframe had not such a nice frequency between the data so that resmpling it resulted in many, many rows full of `NaN`s. I solved this using this line: `data = data_orig.resample( "100ms" ).first().dropna( how="all" )`.